# How to call Assembla REST apis from android program

Tags: android

I want to call assembla apis from my code in android.
I am able to connect to assembla using the code given below, I am getting output in HTMl form.
but not able to understand how to use this data.

Code fragment :

HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {

```
        String authentication = "username:password";
        String encoding = Base64.encodeToString(authentication.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        URL url = new URL("https://www.assembla.com/spaces/my_spaces");
        //URL url = new URL("https://www.assembla.com/");
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         conn.connect();

        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode()); 
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());

        InputStreamReader isr =
            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);

        br.close();
```

I am very new to android so no idea the approach i m using to call rest api is correct or not.
Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I mostly make my api requests.

```
        HttpClient c = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("URL");

        post.addHeader("ContentType","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        List<NameValuePair> httpparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        httpparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(httpparams);
        post.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse resp = c.execute(post);


        InputStream i = resp.getEntity().getContent();
        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(i);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ir);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        ir.close();
        br.close();

        JSONObject user = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
```

You can add or remove parameters if you want.
And I asume you receive a JSON Object (sb.toString())

Edit: In this case it's a POST , you can easily change it to GET (HttpGet)